# Upload an array of images to S3 using aws amplify , react native

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I have a form (I used formik for the form) where you can upload more than one image , in put the images in an array . I would love to know how to upload them to s3

```
          <Form
            initialValues={{
              title: '',
              price: '',
              description: '',
              category: null,
              images: [],
            }}
            onSubmit={(values, { resetForm }) =>
              handleSubmit(values, { resetForm })
            }
            validationSchema={validationSchema}
          >
            // inputs
          </Form>
```

I can actually upload just an image to s3 but multiple images is my problem

Comment: I think the suggested solution is to asynchronously upload each of them individually, so something like an array of images using Promise.all and maybe the Amplify library on the client would work.

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/upload/q/platform/js#encrypted-uploads

Comment: It's been 1 year now, did you find a solution to this? Experiencing this issue too